# Prevent click event jquery

Tags: jquery, events, function, onclick

I have a number of list items that contain images within links. When one of these links is clicked, I want to get containing `li`'s rel attribute only, without following the click event though. Following the event through currently opens the link image up in a new page which I do not want.

I have tried   `return false;` within my function but this doesnt work (see below). I have also tried this on the actual link in the mark up but I would rather not do this as this isn't best practice.

```
 $('a.main-img').click(function (){

    var liRel = $(this).closest('li').attr('rel');
    var relNumber = $('#banner-holder').find('img').attr('id', liRel);
    rotatePics(relNumber);

    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note though that `preventDefault` wont stop the event from bubbling up the DOM and being actioned by and event on one of the parents. The function `event.StopPropagation` will do that. PreventDefault stops the default action of the link. Return false actually does both so using preventDefault won't be an exact functional replication of return false.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false) gives a comprehensive run through.

Probably won't make a difference in this case but when it does it has really confused me in the past

Answer (score 2):

You should learn about `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`

[event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) 
[event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Read, here you have an example.

**EDIT:** Your corrected code will be like this:

```
 $('a.main-img').click(function (event){
     event.preventDefault();
    var liRel = $(this).closest('li').attr('rel');
    var relNumber = $('#banner-holder').find('img').attr('id', liRel);
    rotatePics(relNumber);    
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 $('a.main-img').click(function (evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
```